# Airflow - run dag at different time based on holiday calendar

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'd like to start an Airflow job at different times based on holiday calendar. The requirements are as follows.

1. DAG runs at 5PM on normal day, but 9AM on holiday. Does not run at all over weekend.
2. Other than time, job is identical
3. To find out if it's a holiday, we'd query a database.

I am using `schedule_interval` to specify the start time, like '0 17 * * 1-5' for normal day. My first attempt was to change `schedule_interval` based on the result of the calendar query. Like this

```
with DAG(
    dag_id='jobname',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval='0 9 * * 1-5` if isholiday() else '0 17 * * 1-5'
    catchup=False,
) as dag:
    ## Make python operator to run my task
```

where `isholiday()` takes current date, and checks against database to see if it's a holiday.

This is not desirable for several reasons. The biggest reason is that this code gets called when the DAG itself gets parsed, which Airflow does behind the scene on an interval repeatedly. I actually have many jobs that need to do this - so multiply this by number of jobs, and I'm making many database queries per minute. Our DBA would not be happy to see this many identical queries. There's also no easy way for me to cache the result of the holiday database query since each time Airflow parses the DAG, it runs inside a different process.

The next obvious solution is to setup a separate DAG for holidays.

```
 with DAG(
    dag_id='jobname-holiday',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval='0 9 * * 1-5'
    catchup=False,
) as dag:
```

This job always get invoked at 9AM. Inside the task itself, I could run the `isholiday()` function, and I'd skip If it's a normal day.
Of course, I'd still have the normal DAG to run at 5PM. I'd do the exact opposite check for `isholiday()`. So I'd skip if it's a holiday

This works, but now I have essentially multiplied the number of DAGs by 2, since I have a parallel universe of jobs that run on holidays. Furthermore, these "holiday" jobs run everyday, even though most days they fail. That just seems like extra dagrun, extra log output...extra real estate on the GUI. Extra everything.

The other solution is to run job twice a day - once at the early time, and once at the late time. Inside my task, I'd check the current time and the calendar. If it's early time, and today is holiday, I proceed. Or, if it's the late time, and today is normal day, I proceed. Everything else results in a skip.

```
 with DAG(
    dag_id='jobname',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval='0 9,17 * * 1-5'
    catchup=False,
) as dag:


def task():
    if isholiday() and current_time_is('09:00'):
        print ('ok. holiday and in early run')
    elif not isholiday() and current_time_is('17:00'):
        print ('ok. regular day and normal run')
    else:
        print ('do not run')
        raise
```

This works. But, it resulted in the number of DAG runs doubling. In the Airflow GUI, I'd see double the number of columns, and half of them will always be a fail.

I'd think I'm not the only one with this problem. It seems like none of my solutions are great. How have other people solved it in the past?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

We are addressing this problem in Airflow 2.2 (probably will be released in ~ month).

You will get the possibility of defining very flexible schedules:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/AIP-39+Richer+scheduler_interval

Comment: Thanks Jarek. I took a look at the new scheduler, but I'm not sure how exactly that'd solve my problem.

Comment: You could define your own holiday schedule

Comment: The link does not provide any solution to the problem and the answer itself is missing substance.